# "(Callback method) is not defined" in JSONP access on Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to get data from server using JSONP with jQuery's ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://secure.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json",
    type: "GET",
    data: "msg=aaa",
    cache: true,
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    // jsonpCallback: "callbackmethod",

    success: function(encryptedMsg){
        console.log("Encryption success!");
    },
    error: function(req, errmsg, thrownError) {
        console.log("Error: HTTP " + req.status + " " + errmsg);
    }
});
```

However, following error is shown in error console:

```
Error: jQuery1720502636097747291_1339479763752 is not defined
Source File: https://secure.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=jQuery1720502636097747291_1339479763752&msg=aaa
Line: 1
```

If you open the source file URL, you can see following JSON, and it seems correct JSON.

```
jQuery1720502636097747291_1339479763752({
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged cat",
    // ...
    "items": [
    {
        "title": "Chaton",
        // ...
    },
    // ...
    ]
})
```

I also tried to specify method name with jsonpCallback: "callbackmethod", but it didn't work.
I also used $.getJson() method and jquery-jsonp (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) but the result was the same.

The browser is Firefox and using HTML4.
This is used in a firefox addon.

You can read full code here: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1048275/revision/749
I use $.ajax in getEncryptedMessage function in common-content.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, did you try without specifying the jsonp callback? jQuery should handle that for you.

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I tried to to access flickr in this code and have to specify it, but actually I want to access my own web app. I tried to access without specifying "jsonp:" when I used my own server app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use JSONP in Firefox extensions. If it worked, it would be a security issue because it allowed some web server to run code in the context of your extension. In your case it doesn't work however because [content scripts don't access the web page directly](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/accessing-the-dom.html). The JSONP script gets to run in the context of the web page and cannot see functions defined by the content script.

You should use the [`request` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html) to make requests to any web servers, it supports the JSON format. You cannot use it from a content script of course but you can send a message back to the extension, the extension should then make the request and send the server response back to the content script. See documentation on [communicating with content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html).

Comment: Oh... JSONP was wrong way in Firefox extensions. OK, I'LL try request. Thanks!